# Copy from multiple sheets But not all into one master from last row

Tags: excel, vba

Still new to VBA. I’m trying to copy entire rows from multiple sheets (excluding a few). All sheets are set up the same with headers. I’ve tried using case as you can see below and copy to last row.

I’m not sure how or why I’ve gone wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

```
     Sub copyall()

     Dim wb As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 'Range object
 
 
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook
Set trg = wb.Worksheets("all_rs_tenancies")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         
 'We can start loop
Select Case Name

Case "data_supply", "Options", "all_rs_tenancies"
Case Else

    'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    sht.Range(sht.Range("A2:AA2"), sht.Range("A2:AA2").End(xlDown)).Copy
   
     'Put data into the Master worksheet
    trg.Range("A", Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  

End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True



    End Sub
```

Comment: `trg.Range("A", Rows.Count).End(xlDown)` >> `trg.Range("A", Rows.Count).End(xlUp)`

Comment: Are "data_supply" and "options" worksheet names?

Comment: Hi Tim, it’s still showing up as runtime error 91 object variable not set. Do I need to set worksheet as variable? Thanks

Comment: Hi Michael, yes data_supply and options are worksheet names

Comment: @AdamHartnett when replying to an individual's comment you need to use `@` sign and their name, just like I did in this comment.

Comment: @GMalc will do from now on. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: I take it that the three case worksheets are in the same workbook as `sheets("all_rs_tenancies")` and you have your code in the `ActiveWorkbook`, if correct you should use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. Are there any other sheets in the workbook?

Comment: @GMalc they’re all in the same worksheet, thanks for that tip. 

There are about 15-20 sheets I could do it 1 by one but the 3 named ones are data supply, data validation and the collection sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the code to loop through all worksheet; using `For Each` will set `sht`. `Name` needs a reference to the object (i.e. `sht`). I wouldn't use the `Select Case` statement to exclude the three sheets (and `If` would do) ... but have left it assuming you're going to do something else in that code. This at least will compile. You can debug from here if needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyall()

    Dim wb As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
    Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 'Range object
    
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook
    Set trg = wb.Worksheets("all_rs_tenancies")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'We can start loop
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
        Select Case sht.Name
        Case "data_supply", "Options", "all_rs_tenancies"
        Case Else
        
            'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
            sht.Range(sht.Range("A2:AA2"), sht.Range("A2:AA2").End(xlDown)).Copy
            
            'Put data into the Master worksheet
            trg.Range("A", Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        
        End Select
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: And you need to make the @Tim Williams comment change to the above.

Comment: thanks for that, I knew I missing something but that’s what learning is all about I guess. For some reason my trg.range(“A”, Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).pastespecial keeps coming up as range of object worksheet failed. As I said I’m still trying to learn what’s causing the problems haha

Comment: @AdamHartnett `trg.Range("A", Rows.Count).End(.xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` is wrong because; `Range` does not use a `,` between the column and the row. The correct way is... `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial`. You can use `.Cells` e.g. `.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`, which uses the `,` between the row and the column.

Comment: @GMalc with you and TechnoDabbler this is sorted. Marked their answer as solved now I realise where I went wrong. 
Thanks for the help